# Environment Variable Switching Issue in TypeScript/Node.js Application with PM2

Tags: node.js, duplicates, pm2, dotenv, .env

**Description:**
I am currently facing an unexpected behavior in my TypeScript/Node.js application where an environment variable (SR_URL) seems to switch values intermittently. This issue has started recently, and I'm seeking assistance in identifying the root cause and potential solutions.

**Problem Statement:**
I have defined the SR_URL duplicated variable in my .env file.
The application is transpiled from TypeScript to JavaScript using the TypeScript compiler.
The application is managed by PM2 on a remote server.

**Issue Details:**
The variable recently sometimes takes the value from the top of the .env file (dummy-check-value-replace) and at other times takes the value from the bottom of the file (e00d5d10b97f1abb395a04fe72247a3ea71a9e0f).
This behavior is inconsistent and started occurring without any recent changes to the codebase.

**Sample Code from .env**

`SR_HASH=dummy-check-value-replace`

`SR_HASH=e00d5d10b97f1abb395a04fe72247a3ea71a9e0f`

**Environment:**

| Environment | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Node.js | v18.17.0 |
| TypeScript | v4.5.2 |
| PM2 | 5.3.0 |
| Operating System | Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS |

**What I've Checked:**

- Cleared build caches and restarted the PM2 process.
- Verified TypeScript compilation and inspected the generated JavaScript files.
- Reviewed the PM2 configuration to ensure correct environment variable loading.

**Expectation:**

- As per coding standards the last declared value should be taken when restarting or creating build.